# Galaxy S6 Google Bypass. PLEASE HELP!

Tags: factory-reset, gmail, google-account, samsung-galaxy-s-6, hard-reset

How do I bypass the google verification on my galaxy s6 after I factory reset the phone? Had to reset the phone after an app I downloaded made my phone have a melt down causing me to reset it but now I can not move past the Google setup. When I did the hard reset I was unaware that The gmail verification would be an issue unfortunately I no longer have access to the original google account. how do i get around this so i can use my phone???

Comment: did you use your own account to during the initial setup? if yes you will have to try recover it (but might be a delay of 72hours) Otherwise you will need another workarounds

Answer (score 0):

I wish the phone you are using was not stolen, you are facing **Goolge FRP** issue.

To solve your problem, try this workaround: [Bypass FRP on Galaxy S6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABlfz3qcY2Y).

Comment: Hi! Would you please incorporate information from that link into your answer, so that, if the link expires in future your answer would continue to hold some value. :-)